# Configuring Keycloak provider with SPI

Tags: jboss, config, keycloak

I am trying to configure one of my providers factory (its ID is "phone-verification") with the following code :

```
@Override
public void init(Config.Scope config) {
    String lifespan = config.get("lifespan");
    logger.warn("Lifespan : " + lifespan);
}
```

And I have my configuration done in `standalone.xml` with the following property :

```
        <spi name="phoneVerification">
            <default-provider>phone-verification</default-provider>
            <provider name="phone-verification" enabled="true">
                <properties>
                    <property name="lifespan" value="2592000"/>
                </properties>
            </provider>
        </spi
```

However `config.get("lifespan")` always returns `null`. Is there any extra step or am I doing anything wrong ?

NOTE : I specified the config file with the `/keycloak/bin/standalone.sh --server-config=standalone.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had the same problem and I solved it by replacing the name attribute of spi tag by the name of an SPI type. There is so many SPI types inside Keycloak.

For exemple if your provide is implementing Authenticator SPI you should configure your provider like this:

```
<spi name="authenticator">
   <provider name="Basic-Authenticator" enabled="true">
      <properties>
         <property name="user" value="testUser"/>
      </properties>
   </provider>
</spi>
```

Same If you are implementing a requered action SPI:

```
<spi name="required-action">
   <provider name="Basic-Migration" enabled="true">
      <properties>
         <property name="action" value="login"/>
      </properties>
   </provider>
</spi>
```

Then just use properties in your factory class like:

```
 @Override
  public void init(Scope config) {
    String username = config.get("user");
    LOG.info("This is the provider property: " + username);
  }
```

Don't forget that inside provider tag, the name attribute is the Id of provider in the provider factory class.